# Override Multi tenant Module in Orchard

Tags: c#, orchardcms

We are currently working on a Orchard Module which expose some **services**, **Content Items** , **Layout Elements**  with multiple **categories** for Tenants .

We are trying to override the default configuration page for a new tenant to include what services should be exposed to the tenant .

for example The tenant should only **sees** and **uses**  the *services* and *contents* configured by the default tenant .

what i have in mind is Create a Shell settings with the allowed **Contents/Services ...** and use those settings on the tenant level .

so is it possible to do that ? if so, any guide is much appreciated

EDIT : 

I'm trying to find a way without overriding the shell settings itself since its the main configuration object for a tenant (if its even possible)

ANOTHER EDIT :

I managed to override the ShellSettings Actually . I added the properties i want such as (`string[] ServiceIds`) and edited the views and actions etc .. 
and its working fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Its possible to override the multi-tenancy module as its not a core module .

but adding more properties about the Tenant , I couldn't find any other ways but adding them directly to the ShellSettings .